# mvc in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a problem with mvc in visual 2017 and when I run  a project.it has this error.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4064 The "SharedCompilationId" parameter is not supported by the "Csc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property. test1   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.Compilation.targets   155 
please help me

Comment: Sounds like you're experiencing Roslyn CodeDom Provider issue. Check a [similar issue](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/33) to get started.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Please Install this package

Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers